# Does anyone deploy meanio project to AWS Elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mean.io

I've been trying to deploy a meanio project to AWS ElasticBean but failed. Firstly, it's due to wrong dependencies when installing `npm` with `--production`. Secondly, it's missing `krb5-devel` package which I install via config file below:

```
packages:
  yum:
    krb5-devel: []
```

Lastly, I find it's still now working because the default Node.js environment does not include `Node` and `npm` in the default search path. So the postinstall script for `meanio` package cannot install properly.

I've tried to ssh to the server and add them to the default path, and manually install my project. It works. Then I try to add the `node` path to the config file, but it doesn't work.

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: PATH
    value: $PATH:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/bin
```

Can anyone suggest how to deploy a `meanio` project properly?

Comment: did you check this: http://www.headspring.com/blog/2014-12-08/delivering-mean-stack-applications-grunt-jenkins-aws-elastic-beanstalk-part-1

Comment: I'd like to use elasticbean to do the autoscaling and standardize the deploy workflow, so I don't think I can follow the link. Thanks!